# How do I correctly show price differences in academic writing

Tags: citations, writing

I am writing a text about a new technology in electronics systems.

Here is a problem that I am addressing in the text:

There are people that want to use high frequencies in electronics, but at higher frequencies our connectors become more expensive.

I want to give an example using numbers so that the reader can fully understand how much more expensive it becomes when using higher frequencies. I plan on comparing the prices of connectors capable of operating with current frequencies, and then comparing the prices of connectors that would be needed to operate in higher frequency bands.

There is not really any existing research giving a comparison between price and frequencies. What is a good way to do this? Or is it okay to leave it without any reference since it is just in the introduction?

Comment: Well you definitely need a reference because I am very confused.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you're trying to ask here. I've voted to close in the meantime.

Comment: I don't know about a metaphor, but this seems to be about not being [scalable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) or the [law of diminishing returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminishing_returns).

Comment: Hmm. It seems like with my metafor, I made it unclear what I want to ask. I'll try to change it.

Comment: You could look up some real prices to show the reader the difference, and cite the sources from which you get the prices.

Comment: Another option if you can't get exact numbers might be to cite the reason why the connectors are more expensive (e.g. more expensive materials, lower tolerance for manufacturing defects) and then ball park the increase cost.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there exist connectors that have different specs as regards operating frequency, as well as different prices. 
Simply stating two pieces of actual data "Connector A operates at 10-frequency and costs 100, while Connector B operates at 20-frequency and costs 150" is enough as an example to show that higher-frequency operators cost more to purchase.

If this is all you want to convey to the reader, you're done. You could mak it a bit more elaborate by trying to find a rough quantitative relation, if it exists, say "from the available market data, roughly speaking it appears that doubling the frequency increases price by 50%".

But all these are *purely descriptive*. To my economist's mind, the real question is "*is it worth it*, to operate at higher frequencies?"

What do we gain, if anything, by operating at higher frequencies? More volume of work, however it can be defined? More reliability? More safety? What? And, if we gain anything, *is it worth the increased cost?*

You just entered **cost-benefit analysis**, which is a much more complex task than simply stating some price & specs data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Given those connector costs it is not worth it and is one of the reasons why we are not using the 20-frequency applications, but my research is on an alternative option, which could result in it being viable.